# Determine arc length

Tags: geometry, circles, arc-length

[image in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC5Xm.png)

[image]

I know only the angle BCA. How can I determine the lenght of arc EFG.I don't know the central angle C

[image in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC5Xm.png)

Comment: You could write the whole info given. For example, are the three circles of the same radius?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple...There are tangent lines and parallel lines all over the place 
The answer is 
$$360^\circ-180^\circ-\angle BCA=...$$
which gives the central angle..All you need is the radius.

Note:(I assumed circles have same radii as no information is given.)

Comment: thanks.....i just could not  catch this simple thing for last 2 hours

Comment: why i need to subtract 180 from 360..would you please make me clear?

Comment: It is  $90^\circ+90^\circ$ ..

Comment: sorry .... i did not catch it..can you explain it a little?

Comment: Note the rectangle BDCE..Similarly the other rectangle

Comment: Now i got it.....thanks again